# Unset Data from WooCommerce rest API (all orders and single order) end point

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am developing an app where vendors can see what orders they have received and then ship the desired products to the front store counter.

I would like the only following data to be visible for vendors:

- Order ID
- Order Date
- Order Status
- The Products and its variation(s) (no pricing)
- The Quantity ordered.

I understand that I can filter this information on the front end. But I want to receive only this information as a response, so vendor cannot see any other information in debug console.

I tried different filters but they are not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The `_fields` [global parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/) described in Wordpress REST API docs may fit your needs.

From the docs :

> To instruct WordPress to return only a subset of the fields in a response, you may use the _fields query parameter.

Example :
`https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?_fields=id,status,date_created`

Comment: Thank you but once they have jwt token they can use postman to view the data. How can I restrict JWT token to access only the data I mentioned in my question.